# Photomerge equivalent for Gimp?

Tags: gimp, photo-stitching

I used to use the Automate -> Photomerge option in Photoshop CS3 to stich photos together. Is there an equivalent function in the latest version of Gimp? If so, how do I access/use it? If there is another solution please let me know, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know Gimp itself does not have a way to merge/stitch together photos. There are however various plugins which do this. E.g.

Stitch Panorama
http://stitchpanorama.sourceforge.net/

Pandora
http://www.shallowsky.com/software/pandora/

There's also Hugin:
http://hugin.sourceforge.net/

Hugin is a separate program (not a Gimp plugin), but produces excellent results.

Comment: Stitch Panorama sounds good, but how do I install a plug in for Gimp in Mac OS X?

Comment: @penyuan: Sorry, no idea. Both plugins are scripts (Python and Scheme respectively), so they should work on any platform. Just try installing them according to the generic plugin installation docs (see e.g. http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-scripting.html ). Or just try Hugin first; it has an official Mac binary.

Comment: +1 for Hugin. I've tried the two panorama plugins but none of them are as convenient as Photoshop's photomerge and, unless I missed something, require a lot of manual work. On the other hand, Hugin produces great results quickly and automatically, and is easy to use.